# What app needs iipsrv.fcgi?

Tags: malware, downloading

My Samsung Galaxy Note 8 downloaded three copies of a file called iipsrv.fcgi. I have the apps Gamedia Browser, uTorrent and VLC Media player on my phone and am wondering if this download is related to o e of these apps. Should I be concerned about this being malicious files?

[image]

Comment: Note that you usually can find the app having requested a download by opening the "Downloads" app from your app drawer. It lists the name of the app along with the name of the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. These were actually images I saved from Gamedia Browser, which I was able to open like regular images.